# html2pdf character proglems

Tags: php, html2pdf, html-to-pdf

I am try to convert HTML to PDF file with `html2pdf` library in php, but some HTML tags cause problems especially inside the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags after the conversation text value has a lot of space for each character how to solve this problems

```
require_once('../../pages/HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');

    try {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'tr', true, 'UTF-8', 0);

        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        $html2pdf->Output('doc_help.pdf');
    } catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
```

my output pdf file :

[image]

Comment: Where is your problem content?

Comment: Add an example please

Comment: try tcpdf. it gives so many things which html2pdf aren't

Comment: I am try tcpdf and it worked ,but my pdf files are long so tcpdf run very slow.